# How to add all contents of build folder to installation using Wix#?

Tags: c#, installation, deployment, wix, wixsharp

Im trying to add all output files of a given path to the installation that end in either .exe, .dll or .config, but the ways I have tried so far haven't worked.

This is what I've tried:

```
private static WixEntity[] getContents(string directory)
    {
        WixEntity[] contents = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory)
                        .Where(f => f.EndsWith(".dll")
                                    || f.EndsWith(".exe")
                                    || f.EndsWith(".config"))
                        .Select(f => new File(f))
                        .ToArray();
        contents = contents.Concat(System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directory, string.Empty, System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                        .Select(d => new Dir(d.Split('\\').Last(), getContents(d)))
                        .ToArray()).ToArray();
        return contents;
    }

private static string buildMsi()
        {
            var project =
                new ManagedProject(productName,
                    new Dir($"%ProgramFiles%\\{companyName}",
                        new Dir($"{productName} Files", getContents(clientFolderPath)),
        ***some other irrellevant stuff***);
        }
```

as well as simply doing

```
private static string buildMsi()
            {
                var project =
                    new ManagedProject(productName,
                        new Dir($"%ProgramFiles%\\{companyName}",
                            new Dir($"{productName} Files", new Files(clientFolderPath, f => f.EndsWith(".dll")
                                || f.EndsWith(".exe")
                                || f.EndsWith(".config")),
            ***some other irrellevant stuff***);
            }
```

Using the first method, I only get all the files from the folders but not the nested folders nor their contents.
Using the second method, I get nothing at all.

How can I fix those, or what is an entirely different way I can get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion try to use the recursion method to get all file from folder & nested folder.

Comment: isnt that exactly what i tried? the nested folders dont get installed for some reason the way i did it

Comment: Sorry, As per your questions I thought you need that..Then Please read your questions proper and edit it.. So other can easily understand.

Comment: Are you get all contents in getContens() method? I think you missed contents/file of nested folder.

Comment: i recursively call getContents() to add the contents of the nested folders. but during the installation the folders arent created in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `Files.FromBuildDir(@"your\build\dir\",  ".exe|.dll|.config")`. This should collect all files recursively and preserve directory structure. You can also check corresponding [sample](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/blob/ca8f1a81c25994d5446c38bd6173b7afb76f6112/Source/src/WixSharp.Samples/Wix%23%20Samples/Release%20Folder/setup.cs#L45) or `Files` class [sources](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/blob/master/Source/src/WixSharp/Files.cs) - there are some constructors exists, which may be also helpful.

Comment: cool this works! weird thing is the documentation of Files.FromBuildDir says that its just a simplified version of what I did with the constructor for Files. maybe i messed something in the filter up? thanks anyway!

Comment: In your snippet with `Files` constructor you missed the `\*.*` match pattern and this significantly changed constructor behaviour (and this is by design)